# How to Predicate userinfo.key in UILocalNotification

Tags: ios, iphone, nspredicate, uilocalnotification, predicate

[image]

- Here in my application User set list of task to do in weekdays. So I
  am rescheduling each task at every Friday when user opens the app. So
  I want to know the list of notification which are left.
- so **What I Need** Want to Predicate Timeid or weekday from
  "ScheduleArray".

Comment: Did you try filtering your array using a predicate? What was it? What went wrong?

Comment: int Timeid = [[notification.userInfo valueForKey:@"Timeid"]integerValue];

Comment: I know how to get Timeid but dont know how to use it with Predicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"userInfo.WeekDay = %d", yourWeekDay];
```

or:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"userInfo.Timeid = %d", yourTimeID];
```

Then:

```
NSArray *notifications = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications] filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

Comment: i am getting 0 object